# Destination address from incoming messages

Tags: android, sms

How can I get the destination address from a sms(so that I will have the mobile number of my device) when I receive a new sms in my BroadcastReceiver?

the code:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String myPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

will **not** work since the getLine1Number() method in TelephonyManager retrieves the
             data in
             the "phone number" stored on the SIM card (NOT the phone number
             bound
             to the user's account) - this is often either wrong or
             non-existent,
             depending on the network provider it was shipped from.

I already also checked the [SMSMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getPdu%28%29) Class and I couldn't find any method helping me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not satisfied with `getLine1Number()`, here is what you can try:

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570463/1395993) that shows how to fetch data about sent SMSes, including the destination address (which is what you need, I think). The answer is about *sent* SMSes, but if you change `"content://sms/sent"` to `"content://sms/inbox"`, you should be able to access the received SMS messages. I'm not sure if the inbox SMSes also contain the destination address, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Checked it your way and it does not contain the destination address. Thank you for your reply thought.

Comment: Hm, then I think there is no way to get the destination from the SMS - the data in `sms/inbox` is all the SMS application itself knows.